# CRM2011 SILVERLIGHT BLANK SCREEN ON ENTITY FORM

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I tried to upload my silverlight application(xap file and html file) into crm 2011 from web ressources like the following example : http://geekswithblogs.net/Nilesh/archive/2011/08/30/hosting-silverlight-4.0-application-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx, but I see a blank page when I try to open it.
In my local machine(Visual studio) everthing works fine.
Thank's for your help !

Comment: Is this on premise, online, or hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed the problem,
On my host server I have to specify `<param name="source" value="http://myhostserver/CrmSilverlightApp.xap"/>` Instead of   `<param name="source" value="ClientBin/CrmSilverlightApp.xap"/>`